# Though the user name and password is correct and session also works but redirecting back to login

Tags: session, redirect, authentication, xampp, localhost

Though the user name and password is correct and session also works but redirecting back to login screen in localhost ( when i put the system to another computer it works perfectly)

i want to know what is the problem in my machine

i tried the same system in my other computer with same xampp version and same method but it works perfectly

someone please help me to sort this out

session works perfectly in the machine but redirecting back to login

i'm using codeigniter framework on windows 10 machine

Comment: you need to add detailed (but relevant) information of what is happening exactly

Comment: Did you check htaccess file

Comment: @chmina yes i have checked it , i copied the same files to my laptop it works fine in that

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the lack of root privileges in your machine. If you could post the configuration of your machine or the code then it would help find the bug.

Comment: everything working fine in my laptops localhost
but when i copy the files to my PC and did all the configurations then when i try to log it is redirecting back to log screen
both the laptop and PC is using same version of xampp so i couldn't find what is wrong in my PC